# littering more often in dirty places?

Tags: behavior, criminology

I'm now doing some city management related research and wondering about the idea of high crime areas. Well, the above phrase is a bit extreme. Say, littering, will this kind of behavior occur more often in areas that is already dirty and has tons of rubbish which should not be there? I believe so, however I searched things like littering, wrong parking and etc. on the internet but mostly news or policy. I'm looking for a scientific theory behind the phenomena and thinking of environmental criminology which I konw nothing about.

Any help will be appreciated. New to this site, if anything inapproporiate or unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

After changing some keywords in searching engines, I find the terminology I look for: [Broken windows theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory)

Answer (score 1):

[Tragedy of the commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons) is an economic theory (specifically [game theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory)) that considers both [littering](https://doi.org/10.1111/cico.12360) and [crime](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10610-011-9141-3).

See:

- Pires, S.F., Moreto, W.D. Preventing Wildlife Crimes: Solutions That Can Overcome the ‘Tragedy of the Commons’. Eur J Crim Policy Res 17, 101–123 (2011). https://doi.org/10.1007/s10610-011-9141-3
- Cataldi, J. (2019), The Commons: Separating Tragedy and Triumph at a City Park. City & Community, 18: 88-108. https://doi.org/10.1111/cico.12360

Comment: thx for the information. I have looked through the literature but the tendency that littering more often in a dirtier place is a bit diffferent from the idea behind 'tragedy of commons', which mainly discusses littering in shared fields.

Comment: I -1'd your answer despite its referencing, because it doesn't expand on the contents of the papers. Link-only answers are discouraged as it leaves the answer open for interpretation. As of now it's more of a comment than an answer. Thanks for your active participation on the site though. No bad intentions on this side.